# Navigation menu not redirecting to subpages

Tags: html

I've started html basics and I'm trying to do simple nav menu with 3 sites like this (index on the bottom is main page and these in "podstrona" folders are subpages):

[image]

My code looks just like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" />
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Podstrony</title>
</head>
<body>

<ul id="menu_lista">  
 <li><a href="index.html">Strona Główna</a></li>  
 <li><a href="/podstrona1/index.html">Podstrona nr 1</a></li>  
 <li><a href="/podstrony/podstrona2/index.html">Podstrona nr 2</a></li> 
</ul>  


</body>
</html>
```

I tried different paths as you can see but no one can bring me to any subpage. What should I type to get to them? I searched in web but I didn't find anything helpful with this.

Comment: We have no idea how your HTTP server is mapping URLs onto directories. We don't know where your DocumentRoot is.

Comment: Note: `<link>` does not use or need a closing slash and never has.

Comment: Remove the `/` from the beginning of the second path and `/podstrony/` from the third.

Comment: @Rob — It is required in XHTML. It is allowed (but pointless) in HTML 5.

Comment: Thank you Federico, i didn't think about removing / before path. Now it works perfectly :)

Comment: @Quentin This isn't XHTML.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Absolute vs relative URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're in `podstrony`, remove the first slash of the 1st link, and the `/podstrony/` from the 2d.

When you leave the slash, it means your page will search at the root directory of your server. Without it, the path is relative to the current file path.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" />
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Podstrony</title>
</head>
<body>

<ul id="menu_lista">  
    <li><a href="index.html">Strona Główna</a></li>  
    <li><a href="podstrona1/index.html">Podstrona nr 1</a></li>  
    <li><a href="podstrona2/index.html">Podstrona nr 2</a></li> 
</ul>  


</body>
</html>
```